# Line graph, costant value for missing x-axis data

Tags: spotfire

I have a this line graph:

x-axis = date

y-axis= price

for some kind of products I have only one record for month. Le's suppose I want to see Pepsi and Coke's trend over a defined time period. For Pepsi I have a row with a price for each day, for Coke I only have a row for each month. I would like to visualize Coke's data as if I had a normal daily series but with price constant between months. How could I achieve this results without replicate data?

[image: This Is what I have and what I want]

Comment: Replicate data is how I always solve this problem. You can also go to the plot's properties under Appearance and check the box that says "Draw as step lines". Unfortunately, this will apply that style to all lines in the plot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the data to generate the desired end result.  The software does not allow you to do this natively.